# Docker shell 'ls -l' indenting newlines

Tags: bash, shell, docker

How would I go about setting up the bash shell environment for a docker image, such as `ubuntu:latest`, so that when I run the `ls -l` the output is what I'm used to (straight columns)?

Even with `ls -1` I see every newline starting at the position of the last character of the previous line:

Run container:
`docker run --rm -it ubuntu:latest bash`

```
root@b82014f4ddbf:/# ls -1
                          bin
                             boot
                                 dev
                                    etc
                                       home
                                           lib
                                              lib64
                                                   media
                                                        mnt
                                                           opt
                                                              proc
                                                                  root
                                                                      run
                                                                         sbin
                                                                             srv
                                                                                sys
                                                                                   tmp
                                                                                      usr
                                                                                         var
                                                                                        root@b82014f4ddbf:/#
```

Perhaps I'm missing a .bashrc profile or something else common? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in a recent edge release of docker for mac that causes the linefeed issues. You can revert to the stable release, or upgrade to at least 17.06-rc2, and follow [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1672) for more details as they also need to fix docker-compose.

Comment: I should have checked there :( thank you for linking the issue.